# Forcing Subversion to mark "unversioned" files as resolved and up-to-date

Tags: svn

I am having network problems, so instead of checking out directly, I've copied a coworker's working copy onto my computer. However, he somehow forgot the root .svn folder (all other .svn folders are present). I tried the following:

```
$ svn checkout --depth empty <URL> .
```

And this has gotten svn to recognize it as a repository, but everything is marked as unversioned. How can I tell svn, essentially, "No, really, this is the same file!!! Please just mark it as updated!!!"

Comment: You really copied the repository? Not the working copy? Another thing: Since the format of working copies has changed in latest SVN version you should tell us the version numbers of your coworkers SVN client installation and also your own version.

Comment: Corrected the statement about the working copy. Unfortunately, I don't know what his version was. Mine is 1.6.

Comment: Copy remaining .svn folder too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do nothing without `.svn` folders present in all your working copy directories including root directory.

Excerpt from svn book:

> **.svn** folder is also known as the working copy's *administrative directory*. The
>   files in the administrative directory help Subversion recognize which
>   of your versioned files contain unpublished changes, and which files
>   are out of date with respect to others' work.

[image]

More specifically, as shown on the picture, `.svn` folder contains info about working revision (the one your working copy has) and timestamp of all files in the current directory of working copy.

This information help to define the state of the file. Actually, as shown on the next picture, there are four possible states:

[image]

Therefore, without `.svn` folder there is no way to define whether files in your working copy are the same or different from files in remote repository even though you know they are the same - *subversion does not know*.

**Conclusion:** you should copy exactly the same `.svn` folder as your colleague had in his/her working copy. There is no other way to make it work.

Comment: But could I, for example, `svn add` all files, and run `svn up`, and select `mine-full (mf)` for every conflict? This almost works, but it requires the user to keep hitting `mf` for every single file, and there's also tree conflicts to deal with. Perhaps it's possible to get around these?